# Who is this character and what are her powers?

Tags: dc, character-identification, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-dark-apokolips-war

In the animated movie *Justice League Dark: Apokolips War* there is a character purple in colour whom I cannot identify. Who is this character and what are her powers?

[image]

Comment: Umm, they mention her name multiple times in the movie

Comment: @Shreedhar she only has a cameo in this movie, but yea she was mentioned in one of the previous movies in the series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because it's a semi-original character for the film series.
The character is **[Black Orchid](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Orchid)** who has super strength, durability, flight, and is a master of disguise. But in the movies the Black Orchid is a manifestation (a human form) of the **[House of Mysteries](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/House_of_Mystery)** which is a comic horror anthology series. Her appearance seems to be a new design.

It's first appearance was [Justice League Dark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_Dark_(film)) a movie set before *Justice League Dark: Apokolips War* as part of the Animated film universe.

Comment: [Specific DCAMU DC Database page](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Orchid_(DC_Animated_Movie_Universe)).

Answer (score 2):

The character is [Black Orchid](https://dcanimatedmovieuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Orchid).

Her powers are Magic, Mind Reading, Healing, Flight, and Superhuman Strength.